# Chatter Quick Action Update Record + Post Feed Item

Tags: chatter, quickaction

I want to create a Quick Action where I can update the status of a Custom Object and also Post something on the feed. Something like the File-quick action.

[image: File Quick Action]

I have something like this right now:

[image: My Quick Action]

I want to be able to 'Say something' about the Status Change. Do I need to make a Visualforce Page for this? Or can I simply add the 'Say Something'-field to the Quick Action?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'able to 'Say something' about the Status Change'?

Comment: The same as with a file in the first image. You can upload a file and then add a comment to it which will be visible in the Chatter Feed. I want to change the status and give a comment with is, which will be visible in the chatter feed.
Is this clear?

Comment: Is creating a feed item and then adding a comment (so 2 step process) unacceptable?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt No not directly. But I found an other solution which involves process builder. See the comment on the answer of Gaurav Kheterpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" the problem in another way. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. So what have I done.

Firstly I created a new Custom Field on my object of type Text Area.
You have to add this Custom Field to the Quick Action Layout. So now it looks as following:
[image: Quick action With Comment]

When I click update a Process Builder Flow will be activated. This will check if the Status has Changed and if there was a comment. When this is the case, the text in the ChatterComment-field will be posted to the feed and the field will be emptied after that.

In case there are any questions, ask away!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be using Visualforce Custom Actions along with Chatter Connect API for the 'comment' part, changing the 'status' & doing any other custom operations. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_custom_action_about_the_code.htm) is a good example of how to create a custom quick action using Visualforce custom actions.

You would then need to add your Visualforce custom action as a quick action using the steps mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_custom_action_add_to_page_layout_task.htm).

So, your add comment, status change etc. part will be handled via your Visualforce page.

Comment: Interesting! I came upon an other solution, which will be way easier. But I wanted to check if there was a standard solution. I can add a Rich Text-field to my Object and use that in the Layout of my Quick Action. When the Status is changed AND the field is filled in, a Flow activates and adds that text to the Feed of that Record where the status has been updated.

Comment: Yes, that's an option as well and may suffice if your quick action needs to do things which can be achieved using Flows. If you need to do more custom logic, Visualforce custom actions are handy in those cases.